# How can I know how many queries are fired on my SQL Server from a specific server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Background:
I work for a company where there are two departments using the same master database. Application for one department is developed by my team while for the other department is outsourced. This application are windows based application and several users work on the system concurrently.

Now a lot of conflict is going on due to the extreme load on the master database and we do not have enough statistics to debate.

Now I wish to know, that how many queries are being fired from that other application. Their source code is not available to us.

Is there any simple tool or logging facility which I can setup and then it starts counting the number of queries fired from that server.

Thanks.

P.S: I know a somewhat similar question exists, but it is for mysql and not helping in solving my problem. "[How can i know how many queries are fired in my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741740/how-can-i-know-how-many-queries-are-fired-in-my-database)"

Comment: Check out newrelic. They have some really sick SQL monitoring features that, depending on your setup might be really useful. The are doing all kinds of promos too. You can get a free trial and a t-shirt or usb charger.

Comment: SQL Server already stores a lot of relevant statistics. Eg, Activity Monitor displays active queries and the client that executed them. DMVs can return the same information and more. SQL Server's built-in reports can go into even greater depth. Finally, "Management Data Warehouse" can collect all this information for historical monitoring, queries. What version are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can simply use SQL Server Profiler to get that kind of information. It won't be practical to run it for a long time but if you know when the problems happen, you can just monitor it this way. You can save the output and analyse it later.
2. You can use some commercially available tools to record all the activity in the database. Some of them are very good and allow you to analyse information in great details.

Comment: Yes, it is. But you can filter, e.g. only queries over some number of reads or duration to catch those nasty ones.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is will give you all the Queries which is fired on the server with the specific Database Name on which it is fired......

```
**********************************************************
select db_name(sql_text.dbid) as [Database],
case db_id()
when sql_text.dbid then object_name(sql_text.objectid)
else cast(sql_text.objectid as sysname) end as [Object],
sql_text.text as [AllTSQL],
dbo.GetTSQLFragment(
sql_text.text,
statement_start_offset,
statement_end_offset) as [FragmentTSQL]
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) as sql_text
***************************************************************
```

Please let know if this works

Comment: I also searched in google and found this query but unfortuniately its giving me an error.

Comment: "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Assets", or the name is ambiguous." I am getting this error. I have an "Assets" table in my database.

Comment: I am replacing the code "dbo.GetTSQLFragment" with "dbo.Assets" in above query.

Comment: Check proper syntax. Dont just do blindly copy paste.

Comment: May I know on which version of SQL you tried this query? And was it an enterprise edition?

Comment: @milanm I think you should specify the version you are targeting in the question itself. Tagging with both 2005 and 2008 doesn't help.